# White screen trying to install, log shows call to undefined function ctype_alpha()

Tags: php, install, white-screen

I have looked through every resource I can find for this question and haven't had any luck.

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- localhost successfully shows Ubuntu landing page
- localhost/info.php successfully shows PHP page and extensions
- ctype is NOT listed on the info.php page
- Wordpress functions properly
- I am using the LAMP stack
- I created a database for craft, renamed htaccess to .htaccess in public, altered db.php in the craft/ directory, ensured there are no
  syntax errors, etc, etc.
- Essentially, any of the go to responses I have already tried. I've been dealing with this for 3 days now.
- localhost/craftCMS/public/index.php/admin sends me to a blank white page
- phperrors.log file shows "called to undefined function ctype_alpha()"
- When I try to install php7.0-ctype it installs php7.0-common, but ctype doesn't seem to be there
- This might be a dumb question, but am I actually supposed to go to "example.com/admin"? If so, I receive an "XML parsing error: not well
  formed" when I try that.

I probably missed some details that would be helpful to know, so please let me know if you need any further info. Help on this would be greatly appreciated... I want to compare Craft and WordPress but that's difficult when I can't get Craft running.

EDIT:
Brad's comment about multiple PHP installations prompted me to uninstall and reinstall PHP alone. I had uninstalled and reinstalled everything at some point, but not just PHP. After a purge and fresh installation, and remembering to install libapache2-mod-php7.0, I FINALLY see the craft installation page. Thank you guys for your help!

Comment: Did you install ``php7.0-xml`` as well?  My install line looks something like ``php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-opcache php7.0-mbstring php-imagick   php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-curl php7.0-json  php7.0-mysql php7.0-readline php7.0-xml  php7.0-xmlrpc php7.0-zip``

Comment: Hi, I just tried that (including the rest of your install line) and still the same result and same error in the log files.

Comment: Do you have multiple PHP installs and you're installing against a different one than what Craft is using? From a quick Google search, it looks like `ctype` stuff is included in `php7.0-common`.

Comment: Stupid question: did you reboot apache after you installed those modules? Depending on what you install, apt doesn't automatically kick apache for you iirc. ``systemctl apache2 restart``. If you're not seeing ctype at all when you do ``phpinfo()`` something is definitely amiss with your setup.

Comment: Brad, if I type "which php" I get "/usr/bin/php". If I type "whereis php" I get a long list, including "/usr/bin/php" and "/usr/bin/php7.0". So maybe it is possible that it is using the wrong  version? I will look into it.

RitterKnight, I have been rebooting apache each time I update a module. No luck. But yes, from what I have read ctype is included in php-common, and it does not show up at all in my phpinfo.

Comment: Solved by reinstalling PHP, finally. I'd tried that before but now it worked. THANK YOU

Comment: Awesome... would you mind adding what worked for you as an official answer? Might end up helping someone in the future.